# Get user email

Tags: user-accounts, 2007

I wonder how to get the email for a specific user. I want to send an email to the user that created a specific item in a list. I can get the user by using the following

```
    SPWebApplication webApplication = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
    SPContentDatabase contentDb = webApplication.ContentDatabases[contentDbId];    
    SPList taskList = contentDb.Sites[0].RootWeb.Webs["Subsite"].Lists["Tasks"];
    foreach (SPListItem task in taskList.Items)
    {
        String user = task["Author"].ToString();
    }
```

Is there a way I can get the user email address from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to transfer the "author" field into a proper user type field. 
After that getting the email to the "SendEmail" workflow control is really simple:

```
 //Get the author field as a user
 SPFieldUserValue authorUser = new SPFieldUserValue(workflowProperties.Web, currentItem["Author"].ToString());

       //Set the email TO field like this
        sendCompletedEmail.To = authorUser.User.Email;
```

Comment: Please mark as answer if it work for you Carlos.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to email the creator of an item it would be easiest to do this with a simple workflow.

To grab it in code you can connect to the UserProfileManager and load the user's profile based on the value of the author field.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I did it like this.

```
String userName = task["Author"].ToString();
String user = userName.Split(new Char[]{';','#'})[0];
String email = contentDb.Sites[0].RootWeb.Webs["Subsite"].SiteUsers.GetByID(int.Parse(user)).Email;
```

`task["Author"].ToString()` returns a string that contains the user id and the display name separated by the string `";#"`.